# Start GDB from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, gdb

To start debugging I need to do this steps:

`screen -S gdb_program gdb /path/to/program`

`handle SIGPIPE nostop noprint pass` - is gdb command

`c` - is gdb command

How to write a single shell script which I can run just:

> ./gdb.sh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [Here Document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S gdb_program gdb /path/to/program <<EOF
handle SIGPIPE nostop noprint pass
EOF
```